# DRM client to test the openipmp server on windows

Tags: android, windows, drm

i have installed openipmp server on my windows. They had given some client solution which will work only on visual studio.

I wanted to know that is there any other client available to test openipmp server.

I came to know aboutCloakware’s OMA DRM 1.0 Client for Android.

is it free? is there any link available to download it.

Please help me. Thanks

Manisha Khare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMA_DRM

As for the links to download, u can check out many of the links within the above URL, usually proprietary solutions.

For ann opensource, perhaps this:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/drm/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

All Nokia S60 phones support OMA DRM v1 and most also v2, so if you set up a server correctly, you should be able to test at least basic functionality by simply pointing the phone to the download location of your content files. More advanced features like pushing right objects other the air might be harder though, that would depend on the server.